# Doctrine - Map unique entry to multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I want to have only 1 Entry in the Images-Table, but use it multiple times in other tables. 
The Image-Table has an unique constraint "source" + "source_id".

Doctrine seems to not check this, before saving, so there is an Error: "Duplicate entry ...."

Do I need to search for the joined element by myself before saving?
I hoped Doctrine will do so.

Image Table definition:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="ce_image", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="image", columns={"source", "source_id"})})
     **/
    class Image extends Core
    {
...
```

Event and Date Table definition (identically):

```
class Date {
 .....
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NamesapceTo\Image", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_image", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL", nullable=true)
     * @var Image
     */
    private $image = null;
...
}
```

Comment: can you add your database schema ?

Comment: updated description

Comment: Somewhat sadly perhaps, Doctrine itself does not check any constraints.  The mapping annotation is just used to generate the necessary sql to create the constraint in the database itself.  For most intents and purposes it is up to you to check the constraint before persisting.  Or let sql do it and then deal with the resulting exception.  Symfony has a pretty good [validation library](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator.html).  There are several others out there as well.

Comment: If the `source` and `source_id` columns are added as relations (are they, the property code is missing), you should be applying such logic to check this on the Entity level. Doctrine generates the DB on this config (like you applied), but it's up to yourself to create the business logic. So when you create/add a new `Image`, you should indeed check yourself if you'd be in violation of your business logic. Logically it's not possible to build generic validation for everyone's business logic as that varies per implementation (and explanation, depending on to whom you talk).